# Python: Loading mayavi.mlab throws Attribute Error probably from QT. Loading mayavi works fine

Tags: python, qt, mayavi.mlab

I'm using Python 3.8.8 on MacOS and am trying to load `mayavi.mlab` to draw some 3D plots.

The line

`import mayavi`

works, however the line

`import mayavi.mlab` throws the error

```
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyface/ui/qt4/dialog.py in <module>
     27 # Map PyQt dialog related constants to the pyface equivalents.
     28 _RESULT_MAP = {
---> 29     int(QtGui.QDialog.DialogCode.Accepted): OK,
     30     int(QtGui.QDialog.DialogCode.Rejected): CANCEL,
     31     int(QtGui.QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok): OK,

AttributeError: type object 'DialogCode' has no attribute 'Accepted'
```

I installed PyQT5

`pip install PyQT5`

in the hope that it helps, the error indeed changed.

Now `import mayavi.mlab` throws

```
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyface/qt/QtWebKit.py in <module>
     17 
     18     try:
---> 19         from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
     20         from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import (
     21             QWebEngineHistory as QWebHistory,

ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

browsing a bit on the internet, I saw that a similar error could be fixed by downgrading down to PyQT 5.9.2 through conda.

```
pip uninstall PyQT # installed previously was PyQT 5.15.1
 
conda install PyQT # now installed PyQT 5.9.2
```

Throwing again the error

```
[...]
AttributeError: type object 'DialogCode' has no attribute 'Accepted'
```

I think I'm mainly looking for which version of PyQT (and dependencies) to use with mayavi.mlab